# Do you know about %#x, in C language format string

Tags: c, format-string

```
KdPrint((
         "Unknown IoControlCode %#x\n",
                io_stack->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.IoControlCode
        ));
```

It's weird. What does sharp mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The printf documentation says:

> The character % is followed by zero or more of the following flags:
>
> **#**    The value should be converted to an ‘‘alternate form’’. 
>   For o conversions, the first character
>   of the output string is made zero (by
>   prefixing a 0 if it was not zero
>   already).  For x and X conversions, a
>   non-zero result
>                 has the string ‘0x’ (or ‘0X’ for X conversions) prepended to
>   it.  For a, A, e, E, f, F, g, and G
>   conversions, the result will always
>   contain a decimal point, even if no
>   digits follow it (normally, a decimal
>   point appears
>                 in the results of those conversions only if a digit follows). 
>   For g and G conversions, trailing
>   zeros are not removed from the result
>   as they would otherwise be.  For other
>   conversions, the result is undefined.

MSDN docs on the flags are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8aky45ct(v=VS.71).aspx).

so for `%#x` the value is simply prefixed with `0x`. Where `%x` would yield `34ab`, `%#x` would yield `0x34ab`.

Answer (score 4):

`#` indcates [an alternative format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#printf_format_placeholders). For `x` this means that `0x` is prepended to the output.

Answer (score 3):

[printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) when used with specifier `x`, `#` causes the output to be prefixed with `0x` provided the value being printed is ***other than*** `0`.